# Hibernate @Email annotation on a list

Tags: java, spring, validation, model-view-controller

I want to validate a list off email addresses.
I tried:

```
@Email
private List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.
Is it possible to use the @Email annotation on an array or collection of strings?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using **< Hibernate 5.12** and **Java 8**, you can use type level annotations:

```
private List<@Email String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Do we need to use @Valid here? Only type-level annotation of email is required for the above case, right?